# Create a notification for post field

Tags: wp-query, functions, wp-mail

I have a post type quote with custom fields, I would like to create a notification  that send an email reminder  to the email address set. It reminder is sent when the dates condition matches. I wrote this function script.

```
function set_mail_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}

function notification_fields(){
    // Get the 'Profiles' post type
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'quote',
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while($loop->have_posts()){
        $loop->the_post();
        $days = "30";
        $eventName = types_render_field( "event-name", array( 'raw' => true));
        $email = types_render_field( "email-user", array( 'raw' => true));
        $eventdate = types_render_field( "event-date", array( 'raw' => true) );
        $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($eventdate));
        $date = strtotime ('-30 days', strtotime ($newDate));
        $date = date ('d-m-Y', $date);
        $today = date("d-m-Y");
        $balance = types_render_field( "remaining", array( 'raw' => true) );
        if (!empty($balance) && $today === $date ) {
            $to = $email;
            $subject = "Payment reminder";
            $content = 'Please pay the final payment here';
            /*$from = "no-reply@website.com";
            $headers = "From:" . $from;*/
            $status = wp_mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers);
            add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_html_content_type' );
            return $status;
            remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_html_content_type' );
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    //return;
}
add_action( 'customemail_fields', 'notification_fields',10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you would want is a daily task that sends those reminders, for that you would use WP Cron. I'm not gonna get into the logic of actually building the email (used your code). Here's a basic setup:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'quote_reminder_hook' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'quote_reminder_hook' );
}

add_action( 'quote_reminder_hook', 'send_quote_reminder' );

function send_quote_reminder() {

    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'quote',
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while($loop->have_posts()){
        $loop->the_post();
        $days = "30";
        $eventName = types_render_field( "event-name", array( 'raw' => true));
        $email = types_render_field( "email-user", array( 'raw' => true));
        $eventdate = types_render_field( "event-date", array( 'raw' => true) );
        $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($eventdate));
        $date = strtotime ('-30 days', strtotime ($newDate));
        $date = date ('d-m-Y', $date);
        $today = date("d-m-Y");
        $balance = types_render_field( "remaining", array( 'raw' => true) );
        if (!empty($balance) && $today === $date ) {
            $to = $email;
            $subject = "Payment reminder";
            $content = 'Please pay the final payment here';
            /*$from = "no-reply@website.com";
            $headers = "From:" . $from;*/
            wp_mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're gonna have lots of quotes, I suggest breaking them into batches, and perhaps setting the event to hourly, so that it doesn't timeout or eat your server resources.

I recommend that you setup the cron to be run from your system task scheduler (here's a guide https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-into-the-system-task-scheduler/)

Cron reference https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/

Regards,

Comment: Thank you very much it's send the notification exactly what i wanted.

Comment: If it solves your issue, please mark as answered. Thanks!